# OwinMiddleware instead of message handlers in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I was working on a webapi project & now we are migrating to owin-katana self hosting. OwinMiddleware behaves in a same way as MessageHandlers. So my question is that, If we are using Owin-katana hosting then do we need to use OwinMiddleware instead of message handlers in webapi ?

Please clarify ?

Comment: I would have thought you carry on as you are. OWIN is infrastructure & therefore runs below your application.

Comment: Ok Thanks. The whole concern was to generate the message handlers per request currently these are running over a global object. Is there any way to achive this with owin katana  or using middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use replace ASP.NET Web API MessageHandlers with OwinMiddleware. There is a down side... Your MessageHandler code will be dropping down a logical level in the ASP.Net stack, and therefore will not be able to interface with anything directly in the  Web API level.